# VueJS how to pass two parameters to an Vuex action

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

```
<button class="btn" @click="removeFromTheCart(index,item.price)">
  Remove
</button>
```

I'm passing two parameters to my action **removeFromTheCart**.

```
removeFromTheCart({ commit }, payload) {
  console.log("rooooooohhhhhoooow",payload)
```

When I console log my payload inside the vuex store it **only outputs the index**.
My second parameter wasn't in the output.

How do I get two parameter values through an action?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can send an object as your payload, like this :

```
<button class="btn" @click="removeFromTheCart({ index, price: item.price })">Remove</button>
```

And fetch the data in your store :

```
removeFromTheCart({ commit }, { index, price }) {
  console.log('index', index, 'price', price);
}
```

Comment: I noticed that vue hot reloading has some trouble with this especially if the action had previously a single payload. If someone shoud run into this problem just reload manually.

Comment: It is so tricky, the argument is an object instead of two arguments, thanks a lot!